# In a iOS app, if a timer is scheduled to fire and the app is in background, am I certain that it will fire as soon as the app goes foreground again?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, timer

I a swift iOS app, I have a timer that fires every day (86400 seconds). I have tested the behaviour of the timer when the app is in background, and it seems to me that in that situation, the timer will fire only when the app goes into foreground again. Am I guaranteed of this behaviour ? I want to be certain the timer does fire. It is fine for me if it fires when the app goes in foreground again, as long as it fires then. Thanks

Comment: If you are ok with event being fired when app happens to be in foreground, then you can **Save your last fire *Date* in preferences, and check for this variable at every launch of app in *didfinishlaunchingwithoptions* + *applicationDidEnterBackground* method**, update your preferences with new *Date* object again

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but my concern is when the user never quits the app. I need this timer to fire, also if the app is in background. If not possible, I would like the timer to fire when the app goes in foreground again.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that an application can continue "executing" in the background indefinitely for only a limited number of reasons. Aside from these specific reasons, the app can ask for short periods of time to continue executing in the background. Once these periods are over you tell iOS you are done, in which case the app is suspended, or iOS will eventually forcibly terminate your app (it depends on resources).

So, firing a timer is not one of those specific reasons. However, the processing you are doing with the timer could be!

Your app will briefly be in the background on its way to being suspended. When it is suspended, it is not executing anything -- including the timer.

If your app is terminated (swiped from memory or shutdown by iOS), it isn't coming to the foreground, it is being launched again. And your timer is firing because you are launching your app.

If your app stays suspended, it will come to the foreground. And your timer will fire because of the time interval involved.

Either way you can guarantee that your timer fires.